# How can I make score in Unity 2d for my pong game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pong

So I have created 2 paddles 1ball. The ball has a trail. I created a script to move the paddle and the ball. I have created post processing light to my game and some music. So far everything looks nice and bright. I am only missing 1 thing the score. I really want to make a score using text mesh pro and I have already set up P1 and P2 the 2 names are at the top of the screen. All i need now is to get the score to start. I was already created goal objects on each side and I have already applied an existing script to them that make the ball teleport back to the middle if it hits them. I wanted the score to go uo to 7 and the either say player 1 wins or player 2 wins.

I would love to get some help with this, I have searched all over youtube and google but could not find what I was looking for. I would be glad to get any help please and thank you!

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can make an script Score with reference to both p1 and p2 score text UI;
You need:

- a function to update the results in your Score script with a bool parameter.
- a function in Goal script (the one that detect the ball enter to the goal) will send a bool value
- a var public bool goalP1 in Goal Script
- a references in Goal Script to Score script

Details:

Then in the script of the goal put a expose to inspector variable "public bool goalP1". Put that script in both goals where the p1 makes goal put goalP1 in true and where player 2 makes goal put goalP1 in false; That same script need to have a reference to Score script.
Goal script detect a goal you call a function X that will be sending the value of goalP1 to script score.
Then in Score script you will need a function with a bool parameter if true is goal for p1 if is false goal for p2.

All other logic for score script is easy. save the scores in 2 variables and check everytimne that someone makes a goal if the who makes the goal reach the limit to win or any other rules that you want to apply